# Horizontal Rule that shows hidden comments exist

Tags: feature-request

Reading this [very heavily commented question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4612/43193) I found that when I read those comments to the end, many were "collapsed" comments that I missed, and thus I read comments out of order, and had to re-read quite a bit. Of course now that I am wiser I can try to remember such a possibility when reading future posts. But could there be a graphical reminder? Something differentiating consecutive comments from those with hidden comments in between, such as a dashed horizontal rule, or line that says "2 comments later..." for example?

Comment: I agree. The comments are already separated by a grey line; I think  it should become a thicker zigzag line when intermediate comments are hidden. Let's put a lot of comments under this question to demonstrate the need for this feature. // But seriously, this feature request was [already made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24490/can-we-get-an-indication-comments-are-hidden-between-the-comments/131782#131782) and unfortunately, it's tagged `status-declined`.

Comment: What about this: [Does it make sense to enumerate the comments to a question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7164/19341) I would say: Yes, if it's done automatically...

Comment: @Pavel thank you for the link, I was surprised to not find it in my search. Declined on stackoverflow; does that implie the same for here though?

Comment: [robjon's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/does-it-make-sense-to-enumerate-the-comments-to-a-question#comment26392_7164) about the risk of making comments too much like chat seems pertinent here. (thank you @draks for that link)

Comment: [this idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24498/208114) about having the "show extra comments" at the top would also be a good solution for this I think.

Comment: @adamW The underlying software is essentially the same for all sites, minus add-ons like MathJax and policy details like limits on the number of questions per day/month and whether unregistered users can ask questions. So yes, declined on Meta.SO means declined across SE. // Slim hope: the request was declined by Atwood, who subsequently left SE. I don't know how much the leadership keeps true to the words of the founding father.